# How to move onto the next iteration of a loop within a loop in python?

Tags: python

Take for example the code below with 2 for loops.

```
for xy in set:
        for name in dict:
            if xy == name:
               print("Yay")
```

What I'm wondering is, if after the if statement is found to be true, will it keep iterating through 'dict' or will it go back upto the first for loop and move onto the next iteration? I can't believe how long I've been using python and I don't know the answer to such a simple question.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of iterating over `dict`, why not just test `if xy in dict:`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will continue to iterate in dict. If you want to jump out of the inner loop, use `break`.

You can also try.

```
if any(name in dict for name in set):
    print('Yay')
```

Comment: A very nice solution. I'm not sure how usable it'll be for me because I actually need to keep both of the ids separate to split them and do other things.

Answer (score 4):

It keep iterate through `dict`.

If you want the loop  go back upto first `for` loop, use [`break` statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement):

```
for xy in set:
    for name in dict:
        if xy == name:
           print("Yay")
           break
```

As Jacob Krall commented, You don't need to iterate the dictionary object to check whether key(`name`) exist. Use `in` operator:

```
>>> d = {'sam': 'Samuel', 'bob': 'Robert'}
>>> 'bob' in d
True
>>> 'tom' in d
False
```

---

```
for xy in set:
    if name in dict:
        print("Yay")
```

If you want print `Yay` only once, use [`set.isdisjoint`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint):

```
if not set.isdisjoint(dict):
    print("Yay")
```

BTW, do not use `set` or `dict` as variable name. It shadows builtin function [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set), [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Answer (score 2):

It will continue to iterate over `dict`. If you do not want this behavior try this:

```
for xy in set:
    for name in dict:
        if xy == name:
           print("Yay")
           break
```